# .htaccess doesnot read by apache

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ubuntu

My .htaccess file contains garbages value like

```
'dfdfsdfdsfdfdf'
```

Another file httpd.conf(/etc/apache2/httpd.conf) contains nothing

I expect at least .htaccess file to execute and display page as

`internal server error`

I also changed my code and change both file(.htaccess and httpd.conf) but the page index.php is displaying as if there is no both files(.htaccess and httpd.conf).

What is the cause?

Comment: can you try a `<?php phpInfo(); ?>`?

Comment: Check your httpd.conf file for `AllowOverride` it may be set to none, it needs to be set to all or one of the other variants (that I'm not sure about)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it to work by modifying `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default`
`AllowOverride All` on
`Directory /var/www/` And `Directory /`

Comment: That is actually what I've said 24 days ago. If you expected answer for your **particular** case you had to provide your file/directory structure at least. I don't have extrasensory abilities.

Comment: Also, your answer is useless for others, who could possibly stuck on the same problem.

Comment: I had a same problem as [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13719939/htaccess-doesnt-read-by-apache).

Answer (score 6):

`httpd.conf` should contain `AllowOverride All` for document root directory.

```
DocumentRoot "D:/Projects/Example/htdocs"
<Directory "D:/Projects/Example/htdocs">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Otherwise, usage of `.htaccess` files is disabled.